# How to hide a modal and show another one using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I open a modal, then on click of a div within the modal I want to close that modal and open another one. But when I do this it closes the first modal and only shows the background of the second modal with the body not displayed.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="test-modal" class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
       <div id="option"><p>Click here to show the next modal</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="test-modal2" class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
       <p>modal show after a hide doesn't work?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery is:

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    $('#test-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#test-modal2').modal('show');

});
```

Comment: you dont need the ```hide``` class in modal.

Comment: I removed `hide`. Still the same issue. I just get http://oi63.tinypic.com/qnah5i.jpg the background with no modal displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Stupid mistake the jquery works. I accidently didnt close off the first modal properly which is why the animation wouldnt finish and cause the second modal to not load. I simply put the secondary modal on top of the first modal to test and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

1. Remove `hide` class from modals divs
2. You use `.option` in your selector, but in html you use `id="option"`, so change them

Working [version](https://jsfiddle.net/d1g8ry9g/)

Comment: I removed `hide`. Still the same issue. I just get http://oi63.tinypic.com/qnah5i.jpg the background with no modal displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this data-dismiss attribute on close button.

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```